# Knockout.js, Conditional Observable that Depends on Observable?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Bit of a noob to KOjs and STOF here, have a question,

I have an observable(s), their data is a number 0,1,2, or 3. I would like other observables to hold data that is conditionally set by this data.

example

```
this.isText = ko.observable(data.isText);
this.formatted.isText = ko.computed(function() {
    var it = self.isText();
    if (it == '0') {
      return 'No';
    }
    else if (it == '1') {
      return 'Yes'
    }
    else {
      return 'Not Specified'
    }
  });
```

My example snippet does not function as expected.

What is the proper way to achieve holding a formatted text version of the observable `isText`?

---

How the object is created,

```
function ListItem(data) {
    this.isText = ko.observable(data.isText);
    this.formatted.isText = ko.computed(function() {
        var it = self.isText();
        if (it == '0') {
            return 'No';
        }
        else if (it == '1') {
            return 'Yes'
        }
        else {
            return 'Not Specified'
        }
    });
}

this.loadList = function(data) {
    // console.log(data);
    $.getJSON('someLoader.php', {
      checklistID: data.id,
      checklistRev: data.rev
    }, function(json, textStatus) {
      if (textStatus == 'success') {
        for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
          model.formData.push(new ListItem(json[i]));
        }
      }
      else {
        console.log('Error Competing Request');
      }
    });
  }
```

The HTML,

```
<td colspan="1">
    <select class="form-control" data-bind="visible: status().edit, value: isText()">
        <option value="1">Yes</option>
        <option value="0">No</option>
    </select>
    <span data-bind="text: formated.isText(), visible: !status().edit()"></span>
</td>
```

Everything as a whole works observables get properly declared there are no errors, on first load everything looks ok. If the `isText()` observable gets updated however the `formatted.isText()` does not update to reflect the change. if I do a console log in the terminal, of isText() the value is correct depending on if it has been updated. So on initial load if it was 1 and it was updated to 0 it retains the value 0.

Comment: On the face of it, it looks reasonable.  Can you show a wider scope of what's going on, for instance should it be on a subproperty `formatted`?  When you say it's not functioning as you expect, can you elaborate - do you see errors etc?  Ideally please present your problem as a [mcve].

Comment: Updated, as requested.

Comment: I'm still not seeing where "this.formatted" is defined. When you're setting "this.formatted.isText = ko.computed..." what is the value of this.formatted?

Comment: @JasonSpake I haven't been doing programming for very long, I'm under the impression that when ListItem() is constructed using new it becomes declared with the structure defined in the function definition above. Should formatted also be a observable in this case?

Comment: I figured out what I did wrong, and I updated the Code inside my question to fill in the missing select box from my HTML, this is also where the problem was. I would like to give someone other than myself the opportunity to answer my question, to be fair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is attach a computed to its parent observable. This is a technique I've seen used often by RNiemeyer to keep cleaner code especially when serializing a viewmodel. If so then I think what you want to do is swap the order of "isText" and "formatted" in `formatted.isText`.

As Thibaut Remy's answer already hinted at, you can't attach a computed to nothing, and since "formatted" isn't a thing already you're basically saying `undefined.isText = ko.computed(...)` Instead you should be attaching the computed to the existing observable: `this.isText.formatted = ko.computed(...)`, and calling it similarly in your bindings: `<span data-bind="text: isText.formatted(), visible: !status().edit()"></span>`.

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jlspake/daqxv7r1/)

Comment: I get what you were reffering to now, and I appreciate your help. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your example doesn't work because `this.formatted` is undefined. To get around this, you can (and should) use another variable name instead of trying to nest your variable:

```
this.formattedText = ko.computed(function() {
  var it = self.isText();
  if (it == '0') {
    return 'No';
  }
  else if (it == '1') {
    return 'Yes'
  }
  else {
    return 'Not Specified'
  }
});
```

Comment: `data.isText` is just as undefined in the code presented.  There's a lot of information missing from the question.